# Is there a way to toggle the .append() jQuery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, toggle

I want to appendToggle another img in place of plus.svg.  If you guys know a way to somehow toggle the `.append()` method, that would be great.  I want to change the CSS when you click on it, then change it again, basically.

```
           $(function(){
            $("#btw").click(function(){
                $("#btwl").slideToggle(300);
                $(this).append("<style>#btw::before{content: url(minus.svg);width: 16px;eight: 16px;background-size: 16px 16px;background-repeat: no-repeat;vertical-align: middle;padding-right: 10px;}</style>");
            });
        });
```

Comment: what do you mean `toggle by  the .append() method,` ?? any examples

Comment: You can prepare two CSS classes and then use addClass and removeClass method of jQuery conditionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve the same effect if you use `toggleClass`:

```
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
```

Then in your CSS stylesheet do something like:

```
.selected::before {
    content: url(minus.svg);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Yeah it should. Whatever selector you need will work the same in the CSS as in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the css by providing id to the style

```
$(function(){
    $("#btw").click(function(){
        $("#btwl").slideToggle(300);
        if($('#btwl').is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).append("<style id='toggle_css'>#btw::before{content: url(minus.svg);width: 16px;eight: 16px;background-size: 16px 16px;background-repeat: no-repeat;vertical-align: middle;padding-right: 10px;}</style>");
        } else {
            $('#toggle_css').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).
Put the required style under some class and do

```
   $("#btw").click(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass("requiredClass");
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) Method:

```
<style style="text/css">
    .before::before{
        content: url(minus.svg);
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background-size: 16px 16px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#btw").click(function(){
            $("#btwl").slideToggle(300);
            $(this).toggleClass("before");
        });
    });
</script>
```