# JQuery show hidden content to a particular div on click on li element

Tags: jquery, html

I have some question regarding showing hidden content in a particular place regarding the context.

So I have here this layout:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div style="display:table; margin:auto; width:470px; height:470px; border:1px dashed;">
        <br />
        <div id="ShowPhotoContext" style="margin:auto;">
         Here should come hidden content from li element
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div id="slider1" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="thumbelina-but horiz left">&#706;</div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li> Click me                                        
                    <div class="caption" id="comment_id1" style="display:none;">
                        <p>Some comments to display</p>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li> First menu </li>
                                <li> Second menu </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <div class="thumbelina-but horiz right">&#707;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I have here a list of menu "Click me" when you click on this li element, the hidden content in li, caption should be made visible in the ShowPhotoContext div above.

How can I do that with JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $("#ShowPhotoContext").html($(this).find(".caption").show());        
});
```

Could you try that?

To duplicate your content to the new div try this:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $("#ShowPhotoContext").html($(this).find(".caption").show().clone());  
    $(this).find(".caption").hide();
});
```

Comment: because i should show it in another dif and not in the same spot, but as you can see i have to show it in SHowPhotoContext div

Comment: What do you mean by "where"? It is shown where you entered it in your HTML

Comment: yes i have to show it in another place not in the same ... that is the problem

Comment: Ah, misread the question, will update accordingly. You'll need to use append.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
 $(document).on('click','.menu>li',function(){
   $('#ShowPhotoContext').html($(this).find('div.caption').show())
 });
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc5SL/2/)**

Comment: yeah it works, but how do i clean up before i append, because if i append more it just appends ... is there a function to clean div?

Comment: Use .html() instead of .append()

Comment: to clean up. you can use  `$('#ShowPhotoContext').html('')`

Comment: @Alnedru
Use `html()` in stead of `append()` if you want to overwrite the original content. See my updated answer

Comment: @Alnedru:Updated the answer and fiddle

Comment: one more thing, is there a way to keep that hidden content in li, because when i have 3 clicks on different elements, then it doesn't reappear ... it vanishesh :(

Comment: you need to use toggle class in that case. see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17691768/1719752

Answer (score 0):

```
<menu> <!-- make your structure context-sensitive -->
    <ul>
        <li> Click me                                        
            <div class="caption" id="comment_id1" style="display:none;">
            <!-- ... -->
```

js:

```
var element = $("menu > ul > li:nth-of-type(1)"); // getting the first li in ul in menu
element.on("click", function() { // bind the click-event
    $("#ShowPhotoContext").html($(this).find("#comment_id1"));  // add hidden content to showPhotoContext
    $("#ShowPhotoContext").show(); // and finally display
});
```